# Use a method in a callback

Tags: javascript, oop, callback

Question is being edited. Sorry for changes. Please don't provide answers at the moment :)

If I declare an object in javascript:

```
var MyObject = {
 function myFunction() {
    console.log('hi!');
  }
}
```

Why do I get errors?

Comment: That code shouldn't even run.

Comment: Weird, not getting it in my browser. Am I messing up one of the fundamental ways of writing a js object?

Comment: @DonnyP: What browser are you using? Also, is this the *exact* code snippet you're using?

Comment: I'm an idiot, was loading the wrong js script in my browser. Sorry for wasting your time. Editing question now.

Comment: @DonnyP: Please don't accept answers to questions that don't answer the question. If the answer you've accepted answers your underlying question, edit the question to fit the answer. If not, it makes no sense to "accept" it.

Comment: @DonnyP: Don't edit the question in a way that invalidates existing answers once you got some answers!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Surely it depends on the answer. In this case, for instance, the answer is not an answer to the question actually asked. But at this point, it seems as though what Donny should do is either ask that the question be deleted, or make the question fit the answer he's accepted -- e.g., if Mathieu managed to put his finger on it despite the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it rather be:

```
var MyObject = {
    myFunction : function(){
        console.log('hi!');
    }
}
```

How to call the method:

```
MyObject.myFunction()
```

Comment: This is a *comment*, not an answer. We can take all sorts of guesses at what the real code is.

Comment: Looks like it was the answer Donny P was looking for.

Comment: @ Mathieu: I don't think so (hard to say why he's accepted it), he says he's editing the question. Mind you, it's been a long time now... :-) It's fine if he would edit the question to fit the answer, but as it now, the whole thing is nonsense.